# A noun for the act of brushing one's teeth?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I can't think of a proper word to use here... for example, in a hypothetical schedule there might be this:

> Shower - 9:30
>   Teeth brushing - 9:40

But *teeth brushing* seems very strange/unnatural. Is there a single-word for "brushing of the teeth", as *shower* is to "washing of the body"?

Comment: The reason there's no separate word for "teeth brushing" like there is for "showering" is that teeth cleaning in general can be separated into multiple different categories: brushing, flossing, tongue scrubbing, rinsing of the mouth (with water/alcohol). Meanwhile, hygiene of the body is relatively symple in general: just wash it.

Comment: On a schedule, most people would probably use the infinitive/imperative form of the verb: "brush teeth - 9:40".

Comment: @sumelic What if this were a history log instead of a future schedule, it would have to be changed to "brushed teeth". Or imagine a scenario where one must specify a quantity, ex. "five showers and six brush teeth"?

Comment: Why not just draw shower  symbol and tooth  symbol? Much more easier to glance.

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article on [teeth cleaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teeth_cleaning) gives *prophylaxis*, *odontexesis*, and *odontexis*. However, this medical jargon seems more applicable to the professional cleaning done by a dental hygienist.

I do not know of a one-word noun for "brushing of teeth", but "tooth brushing" might be more natural than "teeth brushing" because noun adjuncts are more often singular than plural.

Answer (score -2):

Just write- **dentifrice**
1. [n] a substance for cleaning the teeth; applied with a toothbrush

http://lookwayup.com/lwu.exe/lwu/d?s=f&w=dentifricing#n/2555378

Comment: Why? That's just a fancy word for toothpaste.